# Openlayers get list of all layers in Geoserver

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-2, openlayers

How can I get a list of all layers deployed in Geoserver separated by Vector/Raster?
Similar to how Geoserver itself does this when one uses the WPS Request Builder (it then shows a complete list of all available Vector or Raster layers - depending on the service one wants to use).

I can only get a list of all layers when I know the workspace (the name of the WMS) they are running in by calling the capabilities of the WMS. I want to be able to recieve the workspave and the name of the layers.

Edit: I just found out one can use the rest API. Thats a nice thing. I can get all layer names by calling http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/layers.json but how can I than seperate those by Vector/Raster?

Comment: Do you plan to work with your own GeoServer or with any GeoServer in the web?

Comment: No with my own Geoserver. Maybe on the same machine but maybe in my LAN. Not decided yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is my final code using ajax and the REST api. Works good so far.

```
var layerList = [];
var loginInfo = ["admin", "geoserver"];
var geoserverURL = "http://127.0.0.1/geoserver";
var raslist = document.getElementById("rasList");
var veclist = document.getElementById("vecList");


$.ajax({
    url: geoserverURL + '/rest/layers.json',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json",
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
         xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(loginInfo[0] + ":" + loginInfo[1]));
    },
    success: function(data){
        for (var i = 0; i < data.layers.layer.length; i++) {
            layerList.push([data.layers.layer[i].name, data.layers.layer[i].href]);
        }
    },
    async: false
});

for (var i = 0; i < layerList.length; i++) {
    getType(layerList[i][1], i)
}

// wait for all ajax elements to stop to proceed with the COMPLETED array - otherwise the asynchronus style of ajax will destroy it all ..
$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < layerList.length; i++) {
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        //option.setAttribute("value", "test" + i);
        option.text = layerList[i][0];
        if (layerList[i][1] == "RASTER") {
            raslist.appendChild(option);
        } else {
            veclist.appendChild(option);
        }
    }
});


function getType(url, i) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json",
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
             xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(loginInfo[0] + ":" + loginInfo[1]));
        },
        success: function(data){
            layerList[i][1] = data.layer.type;
        }
    });
}
```

`rasList` and `vecList` are defined in html of course. This is only the js file to be included in the html.